# determine if "24-hour clock" setting is set

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

What's the best way to determine if the user has set the "24-hour clock" setting to true in Settings-Date+Time on the Windows Phone ?

Can I get this information through the CurrentCulture (CultureInfo) ? I had no luck in finding it.

Comment: You could look for `H` in the time pattern. But there should be a better option, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system clock type can be retrieved using:

```
string clockType = Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Clocks.FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return the string `24HourClock` if the 24 hour setting is on in the device settings or `12HourClock` if the setting is off.

Answer (score 3):

On the back of Dennis' answer, you should be able to determine 24-hour time using `String.Contains`:

```
bool is24HourTime = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortTimePattern.Contains("H");
```

Comment: This doesn't coincide with the setting... just with the culture.

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortTimePattern` way of getting the hour is tied to the culture, and not to the option showing whether 24-hour time is enabled or not. So you will get `h:mm tt` for **English (United States)** and `HH:mm` for **German (Germany)**.

At this moment, you  cannot get this system setting.

Answer (score 1):

For japanese developers, please note.

`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortTimePattern` in the culture `ja-JP` will return the same string `H:mm`, regardless of if the phone setting for 24-Hour time is enabled or not.

Comment: Actually for all cultures the behaviour is as above.