# How to detect time format setting in wp7 programatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [determine if “24-hour clock” setting is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313287/determine-if-24-hour-clock-setting-is-set)

I want to add toast reminder in my app for which I required to know whether the user's phone is having a 12hr or 24hr time format. Is there any way to find this out using C#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property for your task.
Cultures which use 12hr time format have different LongTimePattern property (h:mm:ss tt) and ShortTimePattern property (h:mm tt) from cultures which use 24hr format (H:mm:ss and H:mm).
Use these properties, or AMDesignator and PMDesignator properties which are represent empty strings for cultures with 24hr time format and "AM", "PM" for cultures with 12hr time format.